# Is this a bug in Total?

Tags: list-manipulation, language-design

The output from the last of these lines doesn't make sense to me

```
Total[{}, {1}]
Total[{}, {1, 2}]
Total[{{1}, {1, 1}}, {2}]
Total[{}, {2}]
```

> 0
> 0
> {1, 2}
> 0

The 3 first correctly sums at the given levels, but the last sums at level 1 unexpectedly. Is this a bug?

My alternative to get the correct output:

```
total = Fold[Apply[Plus, #, {#2}] &, #, Range @@ MinMax[#2 - 1]] &
total[{}, {1}]
total[{}, {1, 2}]
total[{{1}, {1, 1}}, {2}]
total[{}, {2}]
```

The thing is `{}` doesn't contain anything with `Depth` 2, so there are no entries to sum, so I would expect the structure to be preserved at the levels below level 2. That's what happen at part 1 when running `Total[{{}, {{2}}}, {3}]` since part 1 is `{}` which has depth less than 3, there is nothing to sum (not even an empty set) so it's left with its structure in the output `{{}, {2}}`.

How can you expect `0` from `Total[{}, {2}]`, but not expect `{0, {2}}` from `Total[{{}, {{2}}}, {3}]`?

Comment: So you don't think `Total[{}, {5}]` is doing the right thing either?

Comment: Up to the documentation, "`Total[list,{n}]` totals elements at level n". Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in  need.

Comment: The second (or any) level of an empty `List` is an empty `List`, i.e., `Level[{}, {2}] == {}`. And the `Total` of an empty `List` is `0`. Consequently, `Total[{}, {2}] == 0`

Comment: Rephrasing OP's doubt: “Since $\mathtt{Depth@\{\}}$ gives $2$, should operations on level $\geqslant2$ of $\{\}$ be *illegal*”?

Comment: @BobHanlon Added an example in the OP, where you also have `Level[{{}}, {3}] == {}`, but `Total[{{}}, {3}]` doesn't contain `0` because it's against the structure of the input.

Comment: @J.M. I don't because there are no entries at level 1, and level 1 is not included in the level specification so you don't sum an empty set. Similarly `Total[{{}, {}}, {5}]` has entries at level 1, both of which has no entries at level 2, and level 2 is not included in the level specification so i expect `{{}, {}}` without any `0` around (`Total` does that right).

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, for the question what to expect, this seems equivalent for the use-case `Total[expr, {k}]` the OP asks about:

```
ClearAll[myTot];
myTot[expr_, 0 | {0}] := expr;
myTot[{}, _] := 0; (* the controversial rule *)
myTot[expr_, {k_Integer}] := With[{
    res = Check[
      Apply[Plus, expr, {k - 1}], (* main equivalence *)
      $Failed, {Thread::tdlen}]},
   res /; res =!= $Failed
   ];
myTot[expr_, _Integer | {_Integer, _Integer}] := "Unimplemented";
```

Examples:

```
expr = {{1, 4}, {{}, {}}, {10, 20}};
k = 1;
Total[expr, {k}]
myTot[expr, {k}]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {{}, {}}
>   {{}, {}}
> *)
> ```

```
expr = {{1}, {10, 20}};
k = 1;
Total[expr, {k}]
myTot[expr, {k}]
k = 2;
Total[expr, {k}]
myTot[expr, {k}]
```

> Total::tllen :  Lists of unequal length in {{1},{10,20}} cannot be added. >>
>
> ```
> (*  Total[{{1}, {10, 20}}, {1}]  *)
> ```
>
> Thread::tdlen :  Objects of unequal length in {1}+{10,20} cannot be combined. >>
>
> ```
> (*  myTot[{{1}, {10, 20}}, {1}]  *)
> ```

> ```
> (*
>   {1, 30}
>   {1, 30}
> *)
> ```

```
expr = {{}};
k = 1;
Total[expr, {k}]
myTot[expr, {k}]
k = 2;
Total[expr, {k}]
myTot[expr, {k}]
k = 5;
Total[expr, {k}]
myTot[expr, {k}]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {}
>   {}
>
>   {0}
>   {0}
>
>   {{}}
>   {{}}
> *)
> ```